# Как правильно создать фон для контейнера?

Tags: html, css

Всем привет. Создаю контейнер

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="image-stack">

<div class="rybak"> 
    <img src="style/Рыбак.gif" alt="">
</div>   
 
<div class="tak">
      <img src="style/Так.png" alt="">
</div>

<div class="pruha">
      <img src="style/Пруха.png" alt="">
</div>

<div class="jor">
      <img src="style/Жор.png" alt="">
</div>

   </div
```

Фоном для контейнера использую рисунок (лежит по адресу  src="style/Пруд.png").
Что надо написать в стилях, чтобы рисунок стал фоном контейнера ? Всем спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Возможно вам подойдет для этой цели css свойство background-image
https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/background-image

Answer (score 0):

```css
.container{
background:url{/Пруд.png} no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="image-stack">

<div class="rybak"> 
    <img src="style/Рыбак.gif" alt="">
</div>   
 
<div class="tak">
      <img src="style/Так.png" alt="">
</div>

<div class="pruha">
      <img src="style/Пруха.png" alt="">
</div>

<div class="jor">
      <img src="style/Жор.png" alt="">
</div>

   </div>
```